# Zip Structure in Python Trying to Read Folders Only

Tags: python

New to Python, an interesting problem I encountered and trying to solve the zip file to identify the top level directory using folders. I do not know how to put words together to make sense. I will write up a pseudo-code to give you the feel of it.

```
for folders in Zipfile.namelist():
    if /zipfile/1folder1/:
          return PASS
    elif:
       /zipfile/1folder1/
       /zipfile/1folder2/
       /zipfile/1folder1/2folder1/
          return FAIL
```

I am interested in reading the folder names, not file names. I tried the reduce() method but to no avail because it will go all the way to the lowest level folder which I do not want. I want only the top level, or the first, folder as in /zipfile/1folder1/. It has to be only and one folder, not multiple folders at the top level directory.

I cannot figure out a method to read the folder and create a for loop iteration to retrieve the index value to determine the number of folders at top level directory.

Thanks!

Comment: that doesn't help because it is not derived from the os system. It's a zip file that an user uploads to the app to open and read the folder and make sure it's only one and one folder, not multiple folders.

Comment: ohh thanks, i thought os can handle  that too.

Comment: Please do not write pseudo-code, but code. And also try to best explain your desired and actual behaviors (with a concrete example). Why is */zipfile/1folder1/* ok (when single), but not when accompanied by the other 2?

Comment: @CristiFati that's what the requirements want. I wish I have the answer. The reason I wrote pseudo-code inside the iteration is because I have no idea how to write it. The actual code is shown below and got what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the workaround to it. It was the `os.sep` including `.split` and `.keys` methods that did the trick and performed the iteration.

```
for folders in Zipfile.namelist()[1:]:
   seps = len(folders.split(os.sep))
   if seps > 2:
      if seps not in dir_count.keys():
         count[seps] = 0
         count += 1
      if count[seps] > 1:
         raise exception
```

Comment: Good that you found a solution to your problem, but it's not yet clear (to me) what the problem was / is. You should have created 2 dummy *.zip* files, one correct and one wrong, to make the difference between them clear.